# Plot with multiple participants

Tags: if-statement, plot, stata, two-way

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQU0i.jpg)

In Stata I would like to plot `ve` (y-axis) against `hr` (x-axis) for each participant in one plot. Each participant (i.e., P1, P3, ...) has different values for `hr` and `ve`. `id` is an extra variable.

I probably have to use the command `if id==1`.
I tried

```
twoway (lowess ve hr if id==1) (lowess ve hr if id==3) (lowess ve hr if id==6)
```

but I am not sure if that is correct.

Which command can I use to plot `hr` and `ve` for the different participants in one plot (like on the picture)?

Answer (score 0):

`if` here is a qualifier, not a command. `lowess` smooths each y variable as a function of the x variable. I would recommend starting with a simpler `line` chart. Something like

```
line ve hr if id==1 || line ve hr if id==3 || line ve hr if id==6
```

is likely to be legal and may be useful. Consider also

```
ssc inst sepscatter 
sepscatter ve hr, sep(id) recast(line)
```

Direct labelling (identifier text next to each line) is more work.